# Image based animation in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, animation

I am trying to implement an image based animation using Swift. I have the image array, duration, and repeat count in the `viewDidLoad`.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var animationImages:[UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!
    ]

    var animationDuration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0
    var animationRepeatCount: Int = 1

}
```

With the auto complete I am supposed to use The CAAnimation property `animationDidStart()`, in the parentheses it says to use `anim: CAAnimation!` How do I use it? I am trying to animate some dice in my `motionEnded` function.

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    dieImage0.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage1.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage2.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage3.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage4.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage5.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage6.image = randomImages.randomDice();
    dieImage7.image = randomImages.randomDice();

    animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!)

    println("Motion Ended")
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. What is your animation supposed to look like?

Comment: I have several 2D images of dice, I want to make an animation of the dice rolling by displaying multiple images in succession. I think I have everything ready, but I don't know how to start the animation when there is a shake gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, the related post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358297/using-a-loop-for-adding-attributes-to-multiple-uiimageviews):

I created a for loop to animate all the images

```
let dieImages = [dieImage0, dieImage1, dieImage2, dieImage3, dieImage4, dieImage5, dieImage6, dieImage7]

for die in dieImages {
    die.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!
    ]

    die.animationRepeatCount = 1
    die.animationDuration = 1.0
}
```

Then I created another for loop in the `motionEnded` method to start the animation and select a random image

```
let dieImages = [dieImage0, dieImage1, dieImage2, dieImage3, dieImage4, dieImage5, dieImage6, dieImage7]

for dieImage in dieImages {
    dieImage.image = randomImages.randomDice()
    dieImage.startAnimating()
}
```

The bit I was having the most trouble with was making the animation start, what you use is `outletName.startAnimating()`, see above.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can do :

```
let animatedImageView :UIImageView = 
    UIImageView(image: UIImage.animatedImageNamed("dicey-", duration: 1.0))
self.view.addSubview(animatedImageView);
```

Comment: From what I can tell that is Objective-C, not Swift, which is what I am using.

Comment: Changed it to use Swift.