# Using a loop for adding attributes to multiple UIImageViews

Tags: ios, swift, loops, animation, uiimageview

I have 8 `UImageView`s that I am adding animations to. I know I can make the animation eight times, but can I use a loop -and maybe interpolation- for it?

Here is my code for the animation:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dieImage0.animationImages = [
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
            UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!
        ]

        self.dieImage0.animationRepeatCount = 1
        self.dieImage0.animationDuration = 1.0


    }
```

And for starting the animation:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        self.dieImage0.startAnimating()  /* <======== */

        dieImage0.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage1.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage2.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage3.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage4.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage5.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage6.image = randomImages.randomDice();
        dieImage7.image = randomImages.randomDice();

        println("Motion Ended")
    }
```

I want to animate each `dieImage`

### Edit

I have several `UIImageView`s with `@IBOutlet`s that I want to animate.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage0: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage5: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage6: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dieImage7: UIImageView!
```

How do I loop through them instead of making a separate animation for each, I already have one animation setup; see above.

### Update:

Everything is working as wanted except two dice have rebelled. The first one (`dieImage0`) consistently lands on a 1, the second one (`dieImage5`) won't do anything at all!

### Update 2:

This is the code I used for my animation:

```
let dieImages = [dieImage0, dieImage1, dieImage2, dieImage3, dieImage4, dieImage5, dieImage6, dieImage7]

for die in dieImages {
    die.animationImages = [
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die1")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die6")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die3")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die5")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die2")!,
        UIImage(named: "dicey-die4")!
    ]

    die.animationRepeatCount = 1
    die.animationDuration = 1.0
}
```

Everything works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the `animationImages`, I would do this:

```
dieImage0.animationImages = (0..<4).reduce([UIImage]()) { images, _ in
    return images + (1..<7).map { UIImage(named: "dicey-die\($0)")! }
}
```

It looks like `animationImages` consists of 24 `UIImages` - 4 sets of 6 images, where the name of the image is `"dicey-dieN"`, (`N` is replaced by a number in the range `(1..<7)`.)

You can create a single array of six images like this:

```
let images = (1..<7).map { UIImage(named: "dicey-die\($0)")! }
```

You want to do that 4 times, and add all the arrays together. You do that with the call to `(0..<4).reduce([UIImage]()) { ... }`

The result will be a single array with 24 images.

Then, as @Chris Slowik suggested, create an array of `dieImages` and then loop through them to assign the random image:

```
let dieImages = [dieImage0, dieImage1, dieImage2, dieImage3, dieImage4, dieImage5, dieImage6, dieImage7]

for dieImage in dieImages {
    dieImage.image = randomImages.randomDice()
    dieImage.startAnimating()
}
```

Your entire `motionEnded` method should probably look something like this:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let dieImages = [dieImage0, dieImage1, dieImage2, dieImage3, dieImage4, dieImage5, dieImage6, dieImage7]

    for dieImage in dieImages {
        dieImage.image = randomImages.randomDice()
        dieImage.startAnimating()
    }

}
```

I think you were running into problems with `dieImage0` because you were starting the animation before you assigned it a random image. Assign the image first, and then start animating.

Comment: Can you explain the first code snippet? Do I need to make any changes so it works?

Comment: I added some explanation to my answer. I don't think you will need to make any changes, but if you have any problems with it, post a follow-up comment.

Comment: In response to your update, I would suggest posting a new question that focuses on the code in your `randomDice()` method. In the `dieImages` array that I created in my answer there was an error - it contained two `dieImage4` dice, and no `dieImage5` dice. That explains the problem with `dieImage5`.

Comment: Actually, I edited my answer again, and I think this time your problem with `dieImage0` should be fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, put the images in an array and loop through the array.

```
for var i = 0; i < dieImages.count; i++ {
    dieImages[i].startAnimating()
}
```

Does that help? A little confused about your intentions, but I think this answers your question